# jQuery - target second radiobutton only when first is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of yes/no radio buttons. I would like a modal window to open when the user clicks an unchecked 'no' radio button only if the yes radio button IS already checked. There is a state where none of the buttons will be checked and in this case I don't want the modal to appear.

My problem is I am showing this modal in a click event on the 'no' button. I have no way to tell if 'yes' was previously checked, since in this scope, we know 'no' is checked because we're inside of the click event for it. Any suggestions?

```
<span class="yesRadioButton" data-questionnumber="1">
    <input id="MHQPreQuestion1_rbQuestAnswerYes" name="YesNo" type="radio"value="Yes" checked="checked">
</span>
<span class="noRadioButton" data-questionnumber="1">
    <input id="MHQPreQuestion1_rbQuestAnswerNo" name="YesNo" type="radio"value="No">
</span>


$('.noRadioButton > input:radio:not(:checked)').click(function () {
    DialogOpen();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an attribute on the "yes" input when you click it, so you know if it has been previously set. Then you can grab the first input through jQuery and check its value before deciding whether you want to have the popup appear inside of the "no" click handler:

```
$('.noRadioButton > input').click(function() {
  var yesButton = $('.yesRadioButton > input');
  var yesValue = yesButton.attr('wasChecked');
  
  if (yesValue === "true") {
    //do your popup
  }

  yesButton.attr('wasChecked', false);

});   

$('.yesRadioButton > input').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('wasChecked', true);
});
```

[Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGmroZ)

edit: updated to work with radio buttons, i was thinking check boxes

Comment: That won't work, they are a part of the same radiobutton group so if 'No' is selected, 'Yes' cannot be selected. Hence, my problem in the click event. Given we are inside of that event, we know that 'Yes' isn't presently selected because we have clicked 'No'. I am trying to determine if 'Yes' was selected before the 'No' click or if nothing was selected before the 'No' click and only show the dialog if 'Yes' was selected.

Comment: hey sorry I was thinking check boxes, I updated to reflect the right solution

Comment: Looks good, how can I set 'wasChecked' to true if 'Yes' is selected on page load?

Comment: I simply did $('.yesRadioButton > input:checked').attr('wasChecked', true); in my document ready function and it worked as expected. Thanks for the help!